# VBA delete Formula Sign from Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing a validation at work and already did a lot of work, but now I am facing a problem. I need to delete the ' sign to clear unwanted Excel Formulas. I tried with Replace but it did not remove the '. Does anyone know how to delete it from a cell?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to clear all formulas, including those masked with ', or you just want to remove apostrophes from formulas to make them functional?

Comment: sorry, for not being clear. The Problem is I have for example the Field "Last Name" and people sometimes write their name inside like 'Ben or +Ben which the crushes the rest of the formulas on their validation and I would like to clear those signs before the actual value, so that only Ben remains

Comment: Can you give an example of what the next formula that breaks would be, because you might be able to edit that formula to ignore any of those characters when they are found, alternatively, this could be achieved through vba by looking at the value and if it contains such character either ignore it or remove it...

Comment: Sure sorry they are quite long and in german!

Comment: You may easily translate formula in any language to English typing in the Immediate window ?Selection.Formula. And, afaik, you cannot remove apostrophe from the beginning of the text in Excel

Comment: can't help without seeing what you're working with and a better idea of what you're trying to do, maybe some screen shots.  Check out [mcve] and [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apostrophe is kept hidden, not as part of the value so you cannot check for it via value or text or formula property. What you need to check for is the PrefixCharacter. Alas, that is read-only.
Only way around this: clear the cell and re-set it.
Short example that you should be able to implement:

```
Dim txt As String, r As Range

Set r = Cells(2, 1)  'contains apostrophe

If r.PrefixCharacter = "'" Then
    txt = r.Value
    r.Clear
    r.Value = txt
End If
```

Put this in an appropriate loop for your cell contents and you should be set.